# How to search for the smallest value in a 4-digit number by using while loop?

Tags: python

For example, "1234" and I want the program knows that 1 is the smallest value. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please explain what have you tried.

Comment: You may want to read [ask]

Comment: why does it need to use a while loop?

Answer (score 1):

This may be of help.

```
x = min('1234')
```

Comment: which is same as `min(y)`